# what is the difference between 均等 and 平等 and 等しい？　All of them can be adjectives

Tags: meaning, nuances, word-usage

What is the difference between 均等 and 平等 and 等しい？　All of them can be adjectives. Could you make some examples to show the difference?

Comment: Have you looked at site like [this one](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/3546305)?

Answer (score 1):

均等 is about evenness/uniformness in the mathematical/physical sense. 平等 is about fairness/equality in the ethical/political sense (i.e., being free from discrimination). 等しい is a wago version that just means "equal", and is often interchangeable with the other two. Unlike typical wago, 等しい is a stiff word (同じ is used in casual situations).

- 正方形を{均等に/等しく}3分割する方法
- サイコロの目は{均等な/等しい/同じ}確率で出現する
- 人権とは人間に{平等に/等しく}与えられた権利である
- 政治家として平等な社会を実現したい
  <sub>(BTW 均等な社会, "uniformed society", sounds to me like a dystopia.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, now I understand the difference